# Invoke property getter Chart not displaying

Tags: javascript, charts, vue.js

I'm trying to build an object that will fit chartJS's model for a line-chart

```
<line-chart :data="{'2017-05-13': 2, '2017-05-14': 5}"></line-chart>
```

I have an API that returns a standard array of objects that I transform like so:

```
getData: function() {
  MyService.getData().then(res => {
    this.data = res.reduce((obj, item) => {
      obj[item.date] = item.value;
      return obj;
    }, {});
    console.log(this.data);
  });
}
```

Result from the API is correctly 'flattened' but in chrome I get this

```
{
  2018-03-05: (...),
  2018-03-06: (...),
  2018-03-07: (...)
}
```

At first I thought that this was the cause of the chart not displaying but it's not.

Here is the complete HTML

```
<div class="data" v-if="data.length > 0">
  <line-chart :data="data"></line-chart>
</div>
```

And the component's data()

```
export default {
  name: 'Graphs',
  data() {
    return {
      listOfStuff: [],
      selectedStuff: "",
      data: {}
    }
  }
```

Comment: How your browser's tool window presents information is not authoritative. You need to learn to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't a problem with the data or how it's retrieved.
The graph doesn't display because of this line:

```
<div class="data" v-if="data.length > 0">
```

*data* being an object, the div was just never displayed...